# Filter out rows based on difference in timestamps in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have data of this format `in SQL Server`:

```
     Timestamp          CustomerID      Product
2019-07-17 21:31:56.000     315          12317
2019-07-19 09:16:43.000     315          55300
2019-07-19 09:41:11.000     315          53100
2019-03-16 18:00:15.000    3141          53100
2019-03-19 18:45:39.000    3141          10328
2019-05-17 10:50:44.000    3141          55300
```

I need to filter out the rows where the product belongs to the same CustomerID group and purchased within 1/2 hour after the previous product was purchased.

**Example :** Row 3 in which product has been purchased by Customer 315 has to be removed as it was purchased within 1/2 hr of the previous product.

**Note :** Product should belong to the same customer while taking the time difference i.e. if 2 products were purchased by different customers within 1/2 hour, they should not be affected.

I can also take the data into `R` and do the manipulation there but i want to reduce the table size as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` with `LAG` to get the timestamp for the customer's previous purchase and then compare those values using `DATEDIFF` to select only purchases not made within 30 minutes of the prior purchase:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, 
         LAG(Timestamp) OVER (partition BY CustomerID ORDER BY Timestamp) AS prev_TS
  FROM purchases
)
SELECT Timestamp, CustomerID, Product
FROM CTE
WHERE prev_TS IS NULL OR datediff(minute, prev_TS, Timestamp) > 30
```

Output:

```
Timestamp               CustomerID  Product
2019-07-17T21:31:56Z    315         12317
2019-07-19T09:16:43Z    315         55300
2019-03-16T18:00:15Z    3141        53100
2019-03-19T18:45:39Z    3141        10328
2019-05-17T10:50:44Z    3141        55300
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62e67/7)

**Update**

As @GordonLinoff pointed out, it would be more efficient not to use `DATEDIFF()` for this purpose, but instead make a direct comparison of the times:

```
WHERE prev_TS IS NULL OR
     Timestamp > dateadd(minute, 30, prev_TS)
```

This allows use of an index on `Timestamp`.

[Updated demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62e67/8)

Comment: Worked, thanks. Also, should I add ```Timestamp asc``` as I want to get rid of the products with higher timestamps?

Comment: @user75252 Good to hear. `ORDER BY` works in ascending order by default so `ORDER BY Timestamp` and `ORDER BY Timestamp ASC` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select                      
cast('2019-07-17 21:31:56.000' as smalldatetime) as Timestamp,     315 as CustomerID,          12317 as Product into TblProduct
union select '2019-07-19 09:16:43.000',     315,          55300
union select '2019-07-19 09:41:11.000',    315,           53100
union select '2019-03-16 18:00:15.000',    3141,          53100
union select '2019-03-19 18:45:39.000',    3141,          10328
union select '2019-05-17 10:50:44.000',    3141,          55300  



select t1.CustomerID, t1.Product, t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp, datediff(minute, t1.Timestamp,t2.Timestamp)
from TblProduct t1 inner join TblProduct t2 on t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID and t2.Timestamp > t1.Timestamp
where datediff(minute, t1.Timestamp,t2.Timestamp) > 30
```